# Why is my value not recognized to be in the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to check if a date string is in an array of dates from a WordPress database. 
Currently, there is only one value in the array: 2019-01-02

If I print the array I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2019-01-02 ) )
```

Why is the value not recognized to be in the array?

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT date FROM wp_table";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    if (in_array('2019-01-02', $result)) {
        echo "Yes, the date is in the array!";
    }
    print_r($result);
?>
```

The there is no result from the above.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Kresten

Comment: Because it is in an object in the array not in the array directly. `in_array ` doesnt check inside objects/subarrays for values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because `in_array` is not suited to an associative (key, value) array.

If you had the following array:

```
array("2019-01-01", "banana", "dog)
```

...it would work.  But it won't work with the keys.

If you are only ever looking for one specific 'key', in this case `date`, you can amend your scope to be only that 'column':

`$dates = array_column( $result, 'date' );`

in your code:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT date FROM wp_table";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    $dates = array_column( $result, 'date' );

    if (in_array('2019-01-02', $dates)) {
        echo "Yes, the date is in the array!";
    }
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your data structure is an **array of objects**, and each one of those contains a field called *date*. To check if a specific date is in that specific array, you should do:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT date FROM wp_table";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    foreach ($result as $res)
        if ($res->date == '2019-01-02') {
            echo "Yes, the date is in the array!";
            break;
        }
    print_r($result);
?>
```